# Magento only https links doesn't work

Tags: magento, hyperlink, https, frontend

I activated the "Secure URLs in Frontend" in Magento 1.9.0.1, but every link is still with http://, even when i call the page https://inserthereurl.com every link is http://.

Do you have any suggestion how to do this?

Comment: have you refreshed the magento cache?

Comment: Yeah. Cleared it in backend and on the filesystem.

Comment: You could just write a htaccess rule to rewrite http to https

Comment: Yeah that would be the workaround. It works, but with every click you have 2 requests and I just want 1. It must be possible.

Answer (score 0):

When you activated it did you also change the "Base URL"? You can check this `System > Configuration > Web > Secure > Base URL`. Check this is set to https not http.

Just enabling "Secure URL's on Frontend" isn't enough, the Base URL also needs completing as this is the one it will use when this option is set to true.

You will then need to reindex your data. `System > Index Management > Select All > Reindex Data`

Comment: Yeah I changed the Base URL, but i haven't reindexed the data. I will try this on monday. Thx at first

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I changed it by setting the unsecure Base URL to https too

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :)